# Datatables: If a column is render cannot be searched

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have a table with one rendered column:

```
"targets": 1,
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        // If it is rendering the cell contents
                        if (type === 'display') {
                            return '<div title = IP:"'+full.IpAddress+'">'+data+'</div>'
                        }
                        return (isNaN(data)) ? -1 : +data;
                    }
```

But when I'm trying to search for a string that the `data` contains it displays `No matching records found`. Is there a way to enable searching also for this column even if it has a render?

I'm new in Datatables, so please be gentle! :)

Comment: This is caused by `return (isNaN(data)) ? -1 : +data;` ....`isNaN()` return true on IP addresses, so all searchable data in your table ends up to be a lot of `-1`'s.

Comment: you are right! That was the reason. Thanks!